# Let f: $\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear function, proof about $f$ and directional derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces

I have this $f$ that is linear and I want to show that for any $a,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$

$f(\begin{matrix}
  a_1 + v_1 \\
  a_2 + v_2 \\
 \end{matrix})$ = $f(\begin{matrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \end{matrix}) + [Df(a)]   \large\vec{v}$

So, it suffices to show that

$[Df(a)]   \large\vec{v} = f(\begin{matrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \end{matrix})$

how can I do this? I can't figure out a way to write down the derivative as anything but a difference quotient at a and that's not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of the derivative, $f$ is differentiable at $a$ iff there is a linear transformation $B$ such that the following limit is zero:
$$\lim_{h\to\vec0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-B(h)}{\|h\|} = 0$$
Since $f$ is linear, you can rewrite the numerator as $f(h)-B(h)$, which is clearly 0 if we
let $B$ just be the linear transformation $f$. Therefore, $Df(a) = f$ and
$$f(a+v) = f(a) + f(v) = f(a) + Df(a)(v)$$

Comment: So really, all we had to do was show that f was differentiable at a, cool. Are you sure we can just take f to be the derivative operator though? It just seems like one out of many possible linear functions.

Comment: If the derivative at $a$ exists, then it must be unique. So since $B = f$ lets the limit go to 0, it must be the derivative. I usually overlook this tiny fact, but look at that it was very useful right now! :D

Comment: OH I see now, so we're letting B just be our function f which gives us 0 so we have that f is differentiable at a.

this part of your statement still confuses me:

"..which is clearly $0$ if we let $B = Df(a)$ just be the linear transformation $f$"

so we're letting $B$ be the derivative of $f$ at $a$ and $f$ itself? what?

Comment: That was a slight abuse of notation. In the limit, if $B$ is a linear transformation and the limit goes to zero, then it is the derivative. I edited the statement, lemme know if it's more clear.

Comment: interesting. so really f must be the derivative in this problem

Comment: what about the converse: clearly if $f$ is NOT linear then this is false?

Comment: You can prove the converse as well, but I'm gonna prove it like this: the equation holds $\to$ $f$ is linear. This is equivalent to your last question.

If $f(a+v) = f(a) + Df(a)(v)$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then by linearity and subtracting $f(a)$ from both sides, $f(v) = Df(a)(v)$. Since $Df(a)$ is a linear function, so must be $f$. Therefore the converse you just asked about is true as well.

Comment: wait, if and only if proves the converse?

Comment: $P\to Q$ and$\neg Q \to \neg P$ are equivalent statements. Proof left to the reader ;)

Comment: haha, true. thank you! you're really good at math unlike me! (see my name)

Comment: Wait, you used linearity of f and then proved linearity of f by D? I don't get it

Comment: can you please come back and address what I said? you didn't correctly prove that the equation holding implies f is linear.

Comment: Whoops! Well, the converse is actually NOT true: Let $f(x,y) = (x,y)+(1,1)$, which is not linear because $f(0,0) = 1$. However, $Df(0)$ is the linear transformation that sends $(x,y)$ to $(x,y)$ and
$f(x,y) = f(0,0)+Df(0)(x,y)$.

Your question holds and is an iff statement when you make the weaker assumption that $f$ is an affine transformation, but it only goes one way if $f$ is linear.

Comment: sorry, yeah! I mixed up the terms "converse" and "contrapositive"! 

In any case, is there a way to do that proof you tried without randomly pulling out linearity and using it to prove linearity? :P